# Data binding to syncfusion grid using custom service not working

Tags: angularjs, syncfusion

I have used syncfusion grid and i want to bind data to syncfusion grid from API 
but data binding to syncfusion grid is not working

here is HTml code for grid

```
<div ng-controller="ContactsController as contact">
   <div id="Grid" ej-grid e-datasource="contact.Cdata"  e-columns="contact.columns" e-toolbarsettings='contact.tools' e-toolbarclick="contact.toolbarHandler" 
   e-editsettings="contact.edittsetings" e-allowsorting="contact.allowsorting" e-sortsettings="contact.sortsettings" e-actionbegin="contact.actionBegin" e-allowpaging="contact.allowpaging"
e-pagesettings="contact.pagesettings" e-editsettings="contact.editsettings" e-allowreordering="contact.allowReordering" e-allowresizing="contact.allowResizing">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is Controller method::

```
function ContactsController(CommonService) {


this.Cdata = [];

var d = CommonService.getCantactList();

d.then(function (response) {

    ContactsController.prototype.Cdata = response.data.Items;;
    console.log("success");
}, function (error) {
    console.log("error");
});
```

}

and the commonService is

```
this.getCantactList = function () {

            return $http.get("http://localhost:63138/api/Contact/GetContactsbyClientId?clientId=1", { cache: true });

}
```

And the API method is::

```
    public object GetContactsbyClientId(int clientId)
    {
        try
        {
            //return (ContactService.GetListByClientId(clientId));
            return new { Items = ContactService.GetListByClientId(clientId) };
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
            {
                Content = new StringContent("An error occurred, please try again or contact the administrator."),
                ReasonPhrase = "Critical Exception"
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be due to the below line.

```
ContactsController.prototype.Cdata = response.data.Items;;
```

It should be as follows.

```
function ContactsController(CommonService) {


  this.Cdata = []; 
  proxy = this;

   var d = CommonService.getCantactList();

  d.then(function (response) {

   proxy.Cdata = response.data.Items;

   console.log("success");
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("error");
 });
```

Now it will work as expected.